# for loop splits double quoted word into two words if there is a space in between

Tags: shell, for-loop, posix, sh

The following command works as expected.

```
$ for i in "foo bar" "baz qux"; do echo $i; done
foo bar
baz qux
```

I was expecting the output of the following commands to be the same. But it isn't.

```
$ list='"foo bar" "baz qux"'; for i in $list; do echo $i; done
"foo
bar"
"baz
qux"
```

What can I do so that when I iterate over `$list`, I iterate only twice, once for `"foo bar"` and once more for `"baz qux"`.

Please provide answers that would work on POSIX shells. I am going to use the concepts learnt from the answer in a shell script.

Comment: Not easy, if you want POSIX compatibility (so without arrays, without null separators in the variables) and want allow `\n` in the strings. Are you sure than this isn't an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? You're trying to solve a puzzle with limitations. It is solveable, but here are (_probably_) easier workarounds by changing the processing logic. _Could you please, describe the problem you trying to solve - e.g. for what do you need such nested quoting?_

Comment: Do you want the double quotes to be part of the value of `i`, i.e. should the first value of `i` be `"foo bar"` or `foo bar`?

Comment: @chepner The double quotes should not be part of the value of `i`. The first value of `i` should be `"foo bar"`. I want the output to be exactly as specified in the first code block in the question.

Comment: @jm666 It could be an XY-problem. I am keeping this question as is in its puzzle-with-limitations form (the Y problem). I have now asked my actual problem (the X problem) here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26008487/1175080

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading from a here document instead:

```
list="foo bar
baz qux"

while read -r i; do
    # Always quote your parameter expansions, in case i
    # starts or ends with whitespace, or contains multiple runs
    # or whitespace, or any pattern metacharacters like * or ?
    echo "$i"
done <<EOF
$list
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate delimited list `\n` in your shell:

```
list="foo bar\nbaz qux"
echo "$list" | while IFS="\\n" read -r i; do echo "i=$i"; done
i=foo bar
i=baz qux
```

Comment: `$' ... '` is not part of the POSIX standard. You could use `IFS="
"` instead. (That's a newline between the double quotes, not a space. Stupid comment box.)

Comment: However, I think the goal is to let `i` be `foo bar`, not `"foo bar"`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for your comments. BASH spoiled me so much that I totally forgot that `$'...'` didn't exist in POSIX. It is edited now.

Comment: You are setting `IFS` to a string containing a backslash and an "n", not a newline. However, there's no need to change `IFS`, since you aren't doing any word-splitting on the input. Also, POSIX `echo` already acts like `echo -e` in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to populate *something* with values with embedded newlines, the one place where this is possible and even easy is the shell's positional parameters. You can manipulate them with `set`.

```
set -- "foo bar" "baz quux"
for i; do    # implicitly for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

If you need to preserve the current script's positional parameters, you might want to do the manipulation in a function, which has its own local scope for positional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problems:

- can't use arrays- not portable
- can't use `$'something'`     #approved by POSIX only for the next version
- can't use `\0` as separator

Because of the above, so you need simulate arrays with ordinary strings, and somewhat speparate the elements. Unfortunately, you couldn't use the NULL character in variables. (for example `dash` isn't support them. The problem is, than the *separator* could exists in the element itself, e.g. you can't use for example the `\t` (tab) because

```
pseudo_array='"foo bar"<tab-character>"baz<tab-character>qux"'
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - content of the element
                        as separator
```

Therefore you must choose a separator what couldn't be commonly in the elements, you could to use for example `\003` (CTRL-C), or `\177` (DEL) characters.

For simulating arrays you need few basic functions, what allows hide the actual implementation. For the following solution, are used the next limitations:

- not using `eval` - can be dangerous
- therefore isn't possible indirect variable settings (no `printf -v` nor `declare`)
- element must allow `\n` or any character except the delimiter

Basic functions:

```
#define the separator character
_sep_=$(printf "\177")  #using DEL (0177) as separator. or use "\003" (CTRL-C)

#in the following, the "$arr" is the variable holding the separated elements

# a_first - returns the first element (not removes it from the string)
# usage: val=$(a_first "$arr")
a_first()   { [ "$1" = "${1#*${_sep_}}" ] && printf "%s" "$1" || printf "%s" "${1%%${_sep_}*}"; }

# a_shift - remove the 1st element and returns the remaining string
# usage: arr=$(a_shift "$arr")
a_shift()   { [ "$1" = "${1#*${_sep_}}" ] && printf "" || printf "%s" "${1#*${_sep_}}"; }

# a_last - returns the last element
# usage: val=$(a_last "$arr")
a_last()    { [ "$1" = "${1#*${_sep_}}" ] && printf "%s" "$1" || printf "%s" "${1##*${_sep_}}"; }

# a_pop - removes the last element and return the remaining string
# usage: arr=$(a_pop "$arr")
a_pop()     { [ "$1" = "${1#*${_sep_}}" ] && printf "" || printf "%s" "${1%${_sep_}*}"; }

# a_push - add element to the end
# usage: arr=$(a_push "$arr" "$element")
a_push()    { [ -z "$1" ] && printf "%s" "$2" || printf "%s" "$1${_sep_}$2"; }

# a_unshift - add element to the start
# usage: arr=$(a_unshift "$arr" "$element")
a_unshift() { [ -z "$1" ] && printf "%s" "$2" || printf "%s" "$2${_sep_}$1"; }

# a_fill - fill the "array" with the arguments
# usage: arr=$(a_fill ... quoted elements....)
a_fill() {
    __a_fill_arr="" #strange name, because the POSIX isn't defined the "local"
    for __a_fill_arg in "$@"
    do
        __a_fill_arr="$(a_push "${__a_fill_arr}" "${__a_fill_arg}")"
    done
    printf "%s" "${__a_fill_arr}"
}

#demo of usage

do_something() {
    local ele="$1"
    echo "Doing something with the element>>$ele<<"
}

#creating an pseudo array
arr="$(a_fill "foo bar" "baz qux" "aaa bbb")"

while [ -n "$arr" ]    #basic check - if the string isn't empty - containing some elements
do
    # iterate backward (for forward use a_first and a_shift)

    element="$(a_last "$arr")"  #get the last element
    do_something "$element"     #do something with it
    arr="$(a_pop "$arr")"       #remove the last element from the "array"
done
```

So, filled the array with the `foo bar` , `baz qux` , `aaa bbb` and prints:

```
Doing something with the element>>aaa bbb<<
Doing something with the element>>baz qux<<
Doing something with the element>>foo bar<<
```

With the above functions you can emulate arrays with *reasonable* precision, for example fill the array from a file:

```
while read -r line
do
    arr=$(a_push "$arr" "$line")
done < file
#use the "$arr"...
```

Unfortunately, they isn't usable in the `for` loop - you must use the `while [ -n "$arr" ]` for test the array length...

Probably exists some more powerful or easier implementation of the above...

*All the above is for FUN only, you really should change the logic of your script, or use some more powerfull language for such processing, like `awk` or `perl` and such...*

Comment: I've heard that `$'...'` might be added to POSIX as well; do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Thanks. I wonder when the next version will finally come out.

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**

---

To iterate, here is a small script that uses a **start pointer** and a **character index** to iterate through the single-double-quoted string:

```
#!/bin/sh

sp=0
index=0
list='"foo bar" "baz qux"'

while :; do
    if [ "${list:$index:1}" = ' ' ] && 
    [ "${list:$((index+1)):1}" = '"' ] || 
    [ "${#list}" -eq "$index" ]; then
        echo "${list:$sp:$((index-sp))}"
        sp=$((index+1))
    fi
    [ "$index" -ge "${#list}" ] && break
    ((index++))
done

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$./itdoubleqt.sh
"foo bar"
"baz qux"
```

Comment: That's not the output I want.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, you want both a separate strings. Hold on.

Comment: `${list:$index:1}` is not part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: Neither is `((index++))`, although you can replace that with `: $((index++))`.